# Comparing a cell with a named range for conditional formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm importing hourly sensor data from 10 different sensors. In short, I want to be able to see when the hourly data exceeds the average usage for that day of the week and time of the day.

I've created sheets named each of the sensor names ("32022", for example) and each of those sheets is a 26 column matrix of the date, all the hours from 00:00 to 23:00, and a WEEKDAY() function to extract the day of the week from the date.

In a separate sheet ("Daily Usage"), I manually created 10 different matrices of the daily average usage by hour for each sensor, with column A being the day of the week (by name) and the following 24 columns being all the hours of the day. Each one of those matrices has been made into a Named Range called "averageusage_32022".

I am trying to iterate through all the data and identify which data is above average for that particular day/time, and change the background of that cell to red if it exceeds the average.

From what I've gathered, I cannot refer to a named ranged in conditional formatting, which is why I'm looking to solve this programmatically.

```
  var currentsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("32033");
  var usagerange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('averageusage_32033');

  //how many rows there are in the sheet
  var firstcolumn = currentsheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var bottomrow = firstcolumn.filter(String).length; 

  //loop through every day, check day of week, iterate through each hour, compare cell to "averageusage" range

  for (var i = 2; i < bottomrow; i++){
    var day = currentsheet.getRange(i,26).getValue;
    for (var j = 2; j < 26; j++){
      if (currentsheet.getRange(i,j).getValue() > usagerange.getRange(day,j).getValue()){
        currentsheet.getRange(i,j).setBackground("red");
        }
     }
   }
```

I'm receiving an error of `Cannot find function getRange in object Range.` I'm assuming that this is because I cannot refer to the named range as I would any normal sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getRangeByName(name)` method returns `Range` instead of `NamedRange`, you need to remove both arguments and `getRange()` method from the one written into `usagerange` (please, note that `day` and `j` will be 0-based for values `Array`). Also, make sure to write values into a variable outside the loop to reduce service calls:

```
var usageVals = usagerange.getValues();
//...loop
if(currentsheet.getRange(i,j).getValue() > usageVals[day-1][j-1]) {
  //do something;
}
//...loop
```

Comment: I tried this, but got the following error: `TypeError: Cannot find function getRange in object Range. (line 18, file "checkAverage")` (the `var usageVals` line)

Comment: Ezra, my bad - `getRangeByName` somehow returns a `Range` instead of `NamedRange`, give me a sec

Comment: Also, there is a small typo in your sample - `getValue` method which result is written into `day` variable should be called, not accessed, thus - `getValue()`